# N length list of nearby ranked elements, excluding matching id

Tags: python, algorithm, data-manipulation

I have two data sets:

- A list of ids, categories, and sorted counts of id occurrence, `grouped_df`.
- A list of ids, categories, and matching names, `label_df`.

I wish to match the category for a given id and then pull n matching names, *excluding the given id*, from a ranked list using only that category. I want ids that are above and below the matched id but not that id itself.

I have something that works for even numbers but not for odds.

```
    def rolling_match(id, n_matches=3):
        
        roll_length = (n_matches//2) # number of positions to move from selected id.
        index_length = (n_matches+1) #length to include from the rolled list.
            
        label = label_df.loc[id][0] # category label
        arr = grouped_df.loc[label] # subset category label
        idx = len(grouped_df.loc[label][(id):])+roll_length #position of first element in list
        indices = np.delete(np.roll(arr.index, idx)[:index_length], roll_length)
        # pulls a rolled list around chosen id and drops that element.
        return label_df.loc[indices]
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I got my version working, the problem is related to Ramesh's point. What confused me was I needed to subtract 1 before mod-division and also add 1 to get the right index length.

```
    def rolling_match(id, n_matches=3):
    
        roll_length = (n_matches-1)//2 # number of positions to move from selected id.
        index_length = (n_matches+1) #length to include from the rolled list.
        
        label = label_df.loc[id][0] # category label
        arr = grouped_df.loc[label] # subset category label
        idx = len(grouped_df.loc[label][(id):])+roll_length #position of first element in list
        indices = np.delete(np.roll(arr.index, idx)[:index_length], roll_length)
        # pulls a rolled list around chosen id and drops that element.
        return label_df.loc[indices]
```

I am interested in recommendations for improving or refactoring this.